# What is a contested waypoint?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I traveled to a waypoint, and died soon after. When I tried to respawn at that same waypoint it wouldn't let me and I saw it was "contested" showing a pair of crossed swords on the icon. I went there running and I found nothing special, but the waypoint was still shown as contested.
What does it mean?

EDIT: The constested status went away, and the waypoint started working again, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A contested waypoint is in an area where an event is occurring around the waypoint, causing the waypoint to be contested. Once the event is over, the waypoint will return to normal.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can temporarily lose access to the waypoint if the event is failed.

Comment: True, I forgot to mention that.